# Prestashop 1.6.0.11: production mode with cache enabled consequences

Tags: caching, prestashop, production

I work with Prestashop 1.6.0.11 and I would like to know what are the consequences (risks) of not disable the cache and not change the production-mode to development mode before changing the site design (colors of buttons, images , icons...), change the code, install modules and add categories and products.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The consequences are that some data will be loaded from the cache, depending on your cache settings.